# How do kafka consumer knows that there is data?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

How kafka consumer api knows that there is new data available in particular topic?

Currently I am calling consumer api every 5 minutes to consume data. If there is a data it will be consumed otherwise it will return nothing.In this case, consumer api is called unnecessarily but I would like to call then api when there is new data available in kafka.

Comment: Why you are usıing api for consuming?

Comment: My consumer application currently built on .net framework 3.5 and confluent kafka dll is not supported below 4.5. That's the reason I created API and called this API from my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know if there is data, however, you can call `poll()` and block until a certain amount of data accumulates (to avoid busy waiting and sending too many request) with an additional timeout.

Check out the docs for details: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

You are interested in `fetch.min.bytes`

Comment: Thank you Matthias.. I think I need set  timeout to infinity.